# Uppercase name in BibLaTeX authortitle citestyle

Tags: biblatex, citing

How can I make an author's name **uppercase** in BibLaTeX `authortitle` citestyle? The statement `\DeclareNameFormat{author}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}` changes the cited references but not the citations in footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{myArticle,
author={Author},
title={Title},
journal={Journal},
year={2000},
volume={1}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
First sentence \autocite [3] {myArticle}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `labelname` instead of `author`:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```